# How to create a generic Makefile that checks sources for any given target name?

Tags: makefile

I want to have a generic Makefile that takes any target name and for that target name, checks to see if certain sources exist and then executes some commands. So for example I want to be able to enter:

```
make mytarget
```

then make should check to see if *mytarget.src1* and *mytarget.src2* exist, and if so execute some commands.

I have the following makefile:

```
%:
    $(MYCOMMANDS) $*.scr1 $*.scr2
```

the only problem with this is that it doesn't check to see if $*.scr1 and $*.scr2 exist before running *$(MYCOMMANDS)*. This is understandable because I haven't specified any dependencies. However when I try:

```
%: $*.src1 $*.src2
    $(MYCOMMANDS) $*.scr1 $*.scr2
```

it now doesn't ever run *$(MYCOMMAND)* and says no rule to make the specified target.

Can someone please explain why in my second code make cannot find the target? Also, how can I achieve the behavior that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write a pattern rule is to use the pattern (`%`) in both the target *and* the prerequisites:

```
%: %.src1 %.src2
        $(MYCOMMANDS) $^
```

See [Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules) in the GNU make manual.  Also see [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables).  By the way, the third paragraph in the second link will explain why your second attempt, using `$*` in the prerequisites, cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the behavior I want using the MAKECMDGOALS variable. So:

```
$(MAKECMDGOALS): $(MAKECMDGOALS).src1 $(MAKECMDGOALS).src2
    $(MYCOMMANDS) $(MAKECMDGOALS).scr1 $(MAKECMDGOALS).scr2
```

does what I am looking for. It checks to make sure .src1 and .src2 exist. If they don't make will report an error and if they do it will run $(MYCOMMANDS).

Comment: This will break if multiple targets are given to make, `$(MAKECMDGOALS): %: %.src1 %.src2 ; $(MYCOMMANDS) $^` is what you're looking for, but this will still break if the respective src* files don't exist. It looks like you're using the wrong tool for the job, use a shell script if you want to execute arbitrary commands depending on the presence of certain files.